# Change the height of NSScroller in NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nsscrollview, nsscroller

I have a NSScrollView, which has NSClipView and vertical/horizontal NSScrollers in it.
Now I want to change the height of the vertical scroller so that it occupies only the top half portion of the scroll view. I can not change the height from the size inspector. I tried changing the frame. It didn't work either.
Can someone help me get through this problem? Thankyou in advance!

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: Override `NSScrollView.tile()`, call `super` and adjust the frame of the scroller.

Comment: Can you use NSScrollView's scrollerInsets property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OS X 10.10, NSScrollView has a `scrollerInsets` property which should be able to position the scroller differently than the scroll view itself, if wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Small world.

I ended up cooking a special component for the 8th pure SwiftUI/FRP incarnation of WhatSize.app
There are things Swift UI can't really do, so you have to wrap NSView objects as NSViewRepresentable and now they are available to a pure SwiftUI app.

```
scrollView.scrollerInsets = .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 14.0, right: 0.0)
```

So the vertical scroll bars do not stomp over the drag and column resize icon on the bottom in yellow.

This allows WhatSize to display data just as Finder's "as Columns" does.

[image]